# How to build up a JSX component tree from an array of renderable components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine we have the following simple react components:

```
const A = function() { return "I'm an instance of A!" }
const B = function() { return "I'm an instance of B!" }
const C = function() { return "I'm an instance of C!" }
```

Assuming the types are formed into an array, as follows:

```
const toRender = [A, B, C]
```

...how can I render each type into a nested hierarchy such that each subsequent index denotes a new child? i.e. B is the child of A, and C is the child of B?

Something equivalent to this:

```
function render()
{
  return <A><B><C/></B></A>
}
```

Comment: I guess there are many ways to implement such a task. Considering we are using the 'array' assumption that means that we cant have 2 children at the same level right?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. I figured out a solution by abandoning JSX and using native `react.createElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using JSX, the following would work:

```
let A = "div"
let B = "span";
let C = "p";
let arr = [A,B,C];

let  nestChild = (e) => {
  if (e.length === 0) return
  let Comp = e.shift();
  return <Comp>{nestChild(e)}</Comp>;
}  

return (
    {nestChild(arr)}
)
```

If you want to work with instances, rather than strings, then you can use:

```
let A = (props) => <div {...props}/>
let B = (props) => <span {...props}/>
let C = (props) => <p {...props}/>
```

Comment: Excellent! 1 minor problem - there are multiple declarations for `C` in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Replacing JSX with native `React.createElement()` this can be done as follows:

```
// @ some render function

const toRender = [A,B,C]; // array with dynamic length
const props = { a: 'random prop' }; // optional props to pass to each element

const lastIndex = toRender.length - 1;
let childElement = React.createElement(toRender[lastIndex], props);

for (var i = lastIndex-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  childElement = React.createElement(toRender[i], props, childElement);
}

return childElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

Years after, but here's a nifty way to do that using reduce. And if we don't care about the order of the components, we can remove the `reverse()` call.

```
toRender.reverse().reduce((ChildrenTree, Current) => (
    <Current>{ChildrenTree}</Current>
), null)
```

Comment: Might be better to just use `reduceRight()` instead of `reverse().reduce()`.